# Inconsistent IIS access across subnets/sites

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7, exchange-2010

Good morning everyone. I have a strange IIS issue I could use some assistance with.

Site setup:

- 2 * Exchange 2010 CAS servers running in a CAS array with WNLB on subnet A
- 2 * Exchange 2010 CAS servers running in a CAS array with WNLB on subnet B
- All servers from subnet A can access the default website on subnet A CAS servers  - ie  `http://subnetacasserver` (which redirects them onto the OWA page)
- All servers from subnet A can also access the default website on subnet B CAS servers
- All servers from subnet B can access the default website on subnet B CAS servers.

However, a selection of servers on subnet B are consistently unable to access the subnet A CAS servers from web browsers. They are able to ping, telnet on port 80 and in general have no other issues other than accessing via web browser. I have tried restarts, IIS resets, checking permissions, resetting IE without any luck.

I’d really appreciate any advice on this peculiar issue.

Comment: What if you bypass nlb?

Comment: Check if there is anything strange in browser proxy settings

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Browser settings appear to be consistent between the servers in question (I have also tried some IE resets, just to be sure).

When taking hosts in and out of NLB, some strange things happen:

 - Subnet A CAS server 1 out of NLB, all servers on all sites are able to access the root website on both subnet A CAS servers.

 - Subnet A CAS server 2 out of NLB, it appears that no subnet B servers can access either of the subnet A CAS server root websites.